# CAUTION: request is not finished! when return json response

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a api code that returns some data like this:

```
return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Successfully created user!',
    'user' => json_decode($user),
    'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    'permission' => [
    'action'=> $action,
    'subject'=> 'all',
    ],
    'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
        $tokenResult->token->expires_at
    )->toDateTimeString()
], 201);
```

i have the same code at login but it works fine.

I tried to debug each piece and found that when I use an array named `permission` it causes a crash, I replace it with `permissions` or random something else it works.
array named `permission` still works with `postman` but crashes on actual run